# Как используя всего одну функцию решить задачу

Tags: c++

1. Функцию generateMasдля генерации одномерного массива из заданного количества элементов
2. Функцию printMasдля выводана экран монитора через два пробела значений одномерного массива из заданного количества элементов
3. Функцию по условию задачи. Название функции должно отражать её назначение.

Используя одну функцию вычислить сумму и количество положительных элементов массива Х[20] и сумму и количество отрицательных элементов массива К[15]

Я могу найти отрицательные и положительные элементы каждого массива по отдельности,а мне как то надо это все запихнуть в одну функцию и я не понимаю как.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<ctime>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std; 
main()
{
    setlocale (LC_ALL,"Rus");
    srand(time(0));
    int X[20],K[15],i,j,SumPositive=0,SumNegative=0;
    cout<<"Массив X"<<endl;
    for(i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
    X[i]=rand ()%50;
    cout<<X[i]<<"   ";  
    if (X[i]>0) SumPositive=X[i];
    }
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Массив K"<<endl;
    for( i=0;i<15;i++)
    {
    K[i]=rand ()%50;
    cout<<K[i]<<"   ";
    if (K[i]<0) SumNegative=K[i];
    }
    cout<<endl<<"Колличество положительных элементов массива X= "<<SumPositive;
    cout<<endl<<"Колличество отрицательных элементов массива X= "<<SumNegative;
}
```

Comment: Написать код для нахождения положительных и отрицательных элементов массива. Засунуть весь тот код в функцию. Вызывать функцию.

Comment: Вычислить всё это в теле одной функции, не?))

Comment: Да в теле одной функции,я не понимаю как это сделать

Comment: А в чем проблема? Создаем одну функцию. В ней по очереди считаем сколько положительных чисел в первом массиве, затем - сколько отрицательных во втором массиве, возвращаем из функции [кортеж](https://qosys.info/tuple-cpp) или массив...

Comment: Начнём с простого: Вы знаете, как создавать вообще любые функции и работать с ними? Простите, если вопрос банальный, но Ваш вопрос никак не иллюстрирует того, знаете Вы это или нет.

Comment: @V-Mor Наверное в этом и проблема ,что не умею

Comment: Тогда вопрос задан неверно. Вас ведь, по сути, интересует не то, как всё это оформить в виде именно одной функции, а как вообще эту функцию оформить. И это Вам явно не сюда, а в книги/туториалы по программированию. Там всё прекрасно объяснено.

Answer (score 0):

Если проблема с выводом данных из этих функций, то можно так:

```
void sums(int* X, int* K) {
 cout << sumPositive(X) << endl; // где sumPositive - функция нахождения суммы положительных элементов
 cout << sumNegative(K) << endl; // где sumNegative - функция нахождения суммы отрицательных элементов
}
```

или так:

```
void sums(int* X, int* K, int& sP, int& sN) {
 sP = sumPositive(X);
 sN = sumNegative(K);
}

int main() {
 //...
 int sP = 0, sN = 0;
 sums(X,K,sP,Sn);
 cout << sP << endl;
 cout << sN << endl;
}
```

В этом случае параметры sP и sN передаются по ссылке, что позволяет модифицировать не копию, а значение переменной, которую вы завели в main.